# What fonts are built in flash player/AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm porting my AIR app to iPad. I'm using embeded fonts in textfields in my app. But when user starts editing text (after double click the `textfield.type` is set `TextFieldType.INPUT`), the text is geting huge... Embeded font is `DejaVuSans`. When I do `textfield.embedFonts=false` the huge font problem disappears. I'm not even trying to ask why the font can get huge (looks like it's specific for my app). The question is a bit more simplier. When I set `textfield.embedFonts` to `false` `Times` font is used. But I need  `DejaVuSans`. Heres the question: how is called in flash player (so that I can do `textFormat.font=NAME`) and where are all available fontfaces are listed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No fonts are built into Flash Player or AIR. Besides embedding fonts yourself, you can use the fonts that are installed on a user's computer (and some fonts are available on almost all OS'es like Verdana and Times).

You can get a list of all fonts on the user's machine via the `enumerateFonts` method of `Font` like this:

(copied from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29)

```
var allFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true);
```

from the manual:

> enumerateDeviceFonts:Boolean (default = false) — Indicates whether you want to limit the list to only the currently available embedded fonts. If this is set to true then a list of all fonts, both device fonts and embedded fonts, is returned. If this is set to false then only a list of embedded fonts is returned.